# Android Conductor - fitsSystemWindows does not work on first controller

Tags: android, android-layout, conductor

With my most recent app, I've decided to use Conductor for the whole of the navigation. It's a single activity app, and everything works fine, except for the splash screen - for some reason, the initial controller refuses to stretch under the status bar, even though the main layout and the controller host are both CoordinatorLayouts with appropriate `fitsSystemWindows` flags.

The host activity:

```xml
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="net.fonix232.app.viewmodel.MainViewModel" />
    </data>

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <net.fonix232.app.common.ChangeHandlerCoordinatorLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</layout>
```

The splash controller's layout:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="net.fonix232.app.viewmodel.SplashViewModel" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        [... splash content ...]

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

The screen after splash:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="net.fonix232.app.viewmodel.SplashLandingViewModel" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        [... splash landing content ...]

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

The first splash layout does not stretch the content (a custom image layer setup) under the status bar, however on the second splash (SplashLanding) screen, it is properly stretched - and since I use shared element transition, I get a nice image resize effect on the background as well.

Where is this going wrong?